# Attempting to maximize some data while minimizing other data.. Essentially an unsupervised question?

Tags: optimization

Suppose I have two columns of data. One is height and one is weight.

$
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
2\\
3
\end{bmatrix}
$
$
\begin{bmatrix}
3\\
1\\
8
\end{bmatrix}
$

So with the above, each row is an individual who's height (column1) and weight (column2) was measured.

Now suppose I standardize these to within 0 and 1. I would be left with;

$
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0.5\\
1
\end{bmatrix}
$
$
\begin{bmatrix}
0.286\\
0\\
1
\end{bmatrix}
$

Now I want to find a person that is in some way tall and light. Naturally Pareto Optimization comes to mind but what about the approach of adding values into a third column.

Since i want light and tall results, can I weight my second vector by -1 and add the vectors together? In this example, the third person weighs a lot and the score would be 0. The first person is the shortest and their score is -0.286. The second person is the lightest while also be moderately tall granting a score of 0.5

What are the repercussions of such an approach? I imagine this isn't really a traditional approach and I've never studied anything of this sort but I'm curious to know where the fault in this thinking lays.

Also, pardon the crude example. It was simply the first thing to come to mind.

Edit: Please note the example is significantly simplified. In reality I would calculate on a set of far more data.

Edit2: This is also assuming there is not special weighting necessary. I.e., weight and height are equally important. This is important to note given the scaling.

Comment: From a basic standpoint, you have desirability criteria here so would need to assign desirability around whether you want to maximise height or use a target plus, minimise weight or use a target. You then find the height and weight that maximise both desirabilities.

Comment: https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pri/section5/pri5322.htm